# Applying a button style to all windows that use a specific window style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a `Window` style in `Application.Resources` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
  <!-- Stuff goes here -->
</Style>
```

I also have style rules that target all buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <!-- Stuff goes here -->
</Style>
```

I also have windows that don't use `MyWindowStyle` where I don't want to use this altered button style. Can I rewrite my button rule so that it only applies in windows that have `MyWindowStyle` set as their style? If you're familiar with CSS selectors, here's another way of putting it: can I use styling logic comparable to `div.MyWindowStyle input[type=button]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the styles. Then button style will be used only within MyWindowStyle.

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <!-- Stuff goes here -->
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <!-- Stuff goes here -->
</Style>
```